# Bigquery: how to select mutiple columns from a where clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I am doing something like this in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    title,
    time
FROM
    abc
where (user_id, time) IN (select user_id, max(time)
                          from abc
                          group by user_id)
```

But I am getting this error:
'Subquery of type IN must have only one output column'

How could we do this in BigQuery? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below will work (note addition of `as struct`)

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    title,
    time
FROM
    abc
where (user_id, time) IN (select as struct user_id, max(time)
                          from abc
                          group by user_id)
```

Meantime, below is more BigQuery'ish way of doing the same

```
select as value
  array_agg(t order by time desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from abc t
group by user_id
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, this works. Could you please explain what this struct does as a part of select query?